# Java Applet - Signing applet class instead of applet jar

Tags: java, applet, digital-certificate, signed-applet

I have a java applet which accesses a file on the file system of the client-side. For that I created a jar for my applet and then signed it and now everything works fine.

**Question:** Is there any way by which I can sign the **applet class itself** instead of first creating a jar and then sign it?

The **reason** why I want to do it:

- because I am launching my webapp from eclipse itself (on the tomcat inside the Eclipse) and then accessing the applet in an **external browser** and the web page loads the **applet jar** and not the **applet class** so I am unable to debug it.
- every time I make changes in the applet class, I need to build the jar and then sign it and then re-pulish the app to the tomcat server for the changes to be reflected. This itself takes a lot of time.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your concrete question, but to cover the last reason you mentioned, you could also just write an Ant build file to automate the JAR build, JAR signing and republishing and let it execute on Ctrl+S of the applet code.

Comment: @Balus I have already created a .bat file for that but i need to manually run it. I don't know how to execute it on Ctrl+S of the applet code.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can debug an applet launched in an external browser in eclipse.

In your applet control panel, in the java tab, under runtime environment parameters

add

-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8888

(where you can pick whatever address you like)

then in eclipse create a new debug configuration, that is remote java application and enter the port (8888) as entered above.

When the applet is running, start the debug session.

Comment: @MeBig.. It sounds, from your answer, like it is possible to debug the applet launched in an external browser even if our html code is pointing to an applet jar and not an applet class. But I didn't get your answer completely. Could you please refer some good brief tutorial on that?

Comment: @MeBig.. Which applet control panel you were talking about?

Comment: The Java Control Panel. look here: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/08/20/debugging-java-applets-in-eclipse/

Comment: and yes, you definitely can debug your code if it's in a jar file.

Comment: @MeBig what "address" denotes? Is it the port on which my tomcat is running?

Comment: no it's the port that the debugger communicates with the applet to fetch information about the running process. You can choose any unused port, so long as both sides agree to what it is.